# Wordpress url rewriting - nice URL with name from SugarCRM

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm developing a Wordpress site, that loads most of the content from SugarCRM.

Currently I get the boats item on URL like

```
http://domain.com/boats/?id=123456789
```

but I would like to have nice URL's, with the name that is loaded from SugarCRM, like

```
http://domain.com/boats/this-is-boat-name
```

Is there a way to do this without creating custom post type and a post for each item in Wordpress?

Comment: Change the Permalink-Structure in the settings,...

Comment: This doesn't help, as I don't see a way to get the end url part dynamically from Sugar...

Comment: you can store the name and their id on the database.

Comment: Without knowing the name before hand, it probably wouldn't be possible to change the id to a name with htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `add_rewrite_rule`.

Have the user access the page via the url `domain.com/boats/12345/this-is-boat-name/`

Then you can pick up the ID in PHP as if it were a `$_GET` query string.

First the rewrite rules;

```
$rule = '^(boats)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?';
$write = 'index.php?name=boats&id=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[1]';
add_rewrite_rule($rule, $write, 'top');
```

And then the filter so you can access the page URL as like a query string

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'id';
    $vars[] = 'pagename';
    return $vars;
}
```

Then, on the page template in your theme, you can pick up the (invisible) query string values like:

```
$id = get_query_var('id');
$pagename = get_query_var('pagename');
echo $id.' '.$pagename;
```

Make sure to flush the permalinks after adding the rewrite rules and filter into your functions.php