# Get parameters from "nice" URL WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

I try to make catalog of cars by using own inserted php script in page in WordPress.
This php script loads data from external database and shows table with informations about cars.

For exmaple we have page `www.domain.tld/catalog/` with the inserted php script.

The script needs one or two parameters `$_GET[‘id_vendor’] and $_GET[‘id_model’]`.

What we need is:

If you input URL

`www.domain.tld/catalog/id_vendor/` or

`www.domain.tld/catalog/id_vendor/id_model/`

then page redirect to catalogue page `www.domain.tld/catalog/` and run the script with parameters.

Our problem is the presentation try to show concrete pages  `www.domain.tld/catalog/id_vendor/` and `www.domain.tld/catalog/id_vendor/id_model/` and shows Error 404 because this pages does not exists.

We need this URLs only for input the parametrs into the script on page `www.domain.tld/catalog/`

Can this be done?
I think I may have to do this with .htacces but I'm not sure how.

Or do you have any other idea how to input paramters to the inserted php script from URL in WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

In Wordpress template is script `functions.php`.

Into this script I added functions:

#
1 (page_id is ID of page where you have your code)

```
function supported_cars_rewrite_basic() {

add_rewrite_rule('^catalog/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=1254&id_vendor=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('^catalog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=1254&id_vendor=$matches[1]&id_model=$matches[2]', 'top');

}
add_action('init', 'supported_cars_rewrite_basic', 10, 0);
```

#
2

```
function supported_cars_rewrite_tag() {
add_rewrite_tag('%id_vendor%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%id_model%', '([^&]+)');

}
add_action('init', 'supported_cars_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

#
3

```
function ajaxCall($url = null){
if(is_null($url)){
return json_decode(null);
}
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);      
return json_decode($output, true);
}
```

And in the page `www.domain.tld/catalog/` I added this code:

```
// Read parameters
get_header();
global $wp_query;

// Query parametres in fnc supported_cars_rewire_tags
echo "<br />";
echo "<p>Vendor: " . $wp_query->query_vars['id_vendor'] . '</p>';
echo "<p>Model: " .   $wp_query->query_vars['id_model'] . '</p>';
```

Other answers that helped me:

[Wordpress url rewriting - nice URL with name from SugarCRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645942/wordpress-url-rewriting-nice-url-with-name-from-sugarcrm?rq=1)

[URL rewriting via Wordpress Rewrite or .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664579/url-rewriting-via-wordpress-rewrite-or-htaccess?rq=1)